# Wicked_PDF changing filename according to id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I am using wicked_pdf in rails3. No problem generating pdf or saving them. My only issue is I want to dynamically name the files according to the @post.id. When I put the following code my file comes out being named #{@post.id}. What am I doing wrong. Thanks

```
def show
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
render :pdf => '#{@post.id}',
:layout => 'layouts/layout1.html.erb',
:template => 'posts/show.html.erb',

:save_to_file => Rails.root.join('public','pdfs', '#{@post.id}' + ".pdf")
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

interpolation only works if you use DOUBLE QUOTES.

just do `"#{@post.id}"` and you're all set